# jQuery Mobile Popup not working on DudaMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can anyone help me out here. I am trying to use a jQuery mobile popup link in DudaMobile. I have managed to get jQuery Mobile and css loaded correctly and I believe I have the correct markup. This works perfectly outside of DudaMobile. Are there any obvious reasons why this doesn't work?

http://mobile.dudamobile.com/site/bbowt?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbowt.org.uk%2Fnode%2F18268#2805

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To fix that click help on DudaMobile http://support.dudamobile.com/ At the bottom you will see, send an email. click on it and type in your issue and click send.

Comment: Yeah I have got in touch with duda mobile, still waiting for their response. Just wanted to make sure their wasn't anything obvious I was missing.

Comment: I suggested that because i had a look around and i couldn't find an answer, Is DudaMobile compatible with JQM Apps?

Comment: I got a response from Duda Mobile that was quite disappointing:

"Unfortunately not all JQuery is compatible with Duda as we use a specific version of it. Currently JQuery Mobile is not part of the the JQuery being used."

This is despite loading a newer version jQuery. Oh well looks like I'm stuck.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No probs, its a shame because Duda can add some extra niceness to JQM with ease

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, it looks like it's not possible. Response from Duda Mobile:

"Unfortunately not all JQuery is compatible with Duda as we use a specific version of it. Currently JQuery Mobile is not part of the the JQuery being used."

This was true two years ago and I have moved on from that now so can't verify if it still is.